# Issue when using Opendaylight on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, sdn, mininet, opendaylight

I am trying to set up an SDN environment using OpenDaylight and Mininet on an Ubuntu16.04 server (not in VMs).

I downloaded the pre-built ODL and installed the following features:

`odl-dlux-all, odl-dluxapp-applications,odl-restconf-all, odl-l2switch-all, odl-openflowplugin-all`

I downloaded Mininet 2.2.2 and connected it to OLD using this command:

```
sudo mn --controller=remote,ip=127.0.0.1
```

However, when I check the ODL GUI, no switch is shown in the topology and nodes. I also checked directly from Restconf API, and it is empty as well. I have tried multiple versions of OLD (Oxygen, Nitrogen SR2, Carbon SR3 and Beryllium-SR4) without any luck. However, it works fine when I use a Ubuntu 14.04 desktop.

Does anyone have experience on this problem in 16.04 environment?

Answer (score 0):

you have to put the port of the controller like this

`sudo mn --controller=remote,ip=127.0.0.1,port=6633`

Comment: I also tried both port 6633 and 6653. Neither works.

Comment: can you try to install these feature too,,,
odl-dluxapps-nodes
odl-dluxapps-topology
odl-dluxapps-yangui
odl-dluxapps-yangvisualizer
odl-dluxapps-yangman,,,, notice its dluxapp not dlux,,, its from this page http://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-nitrogen/getting-started-guide/common-features/dlux.html

Comment: also check if port 6633 is open or not,, plus instead of ip=127.0.0.1 try to use your external IP like(192.168.x.x) and check if it work or not

Comment: I checked that both 6653 and 6633 are open and listening for connection. I have installed all dluxapp features. I also tried to use the external IP address in mininet. However, all these work doesn't help fix the issue.

Comment: no idea,,, one more thing,,,can you exec these command, "sudo ovs-vsctl add-br br0" ,and then  "sudo ovs-vsctl set-controller br0 tcp:controllerIP:6633",, with these command you create one ovs bridge(br0) and set its controller... if all good, now you can see one switch on the odl dlux page... test it and check if that work or not,, if it work there is something wrong with your Mininet instalation